# getting client id of a control from variable

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want the client id of an asp.net textbox control(txtTest) in javascript.But the problem here is the control id comes from a variable as shown below

```
var testName = 'txtTest';
var testCntrl = document.getElementById('<%=' + testName + '.ClientID %>');
```

But its throwing

> CS1012: Too many characters in
>   character literal

Can any one please help....

Comment: How does javascript code generate compiler errors in the C# compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%= aspControlID.ClientID %> is a server side control, but you are trying to pass a clientside variable name to it.  By the time testName is set equal to 'txtTest' its too late, you're already on the client.

There are a number of alternatives to get the server side ClientIDs as [Rick Stahl discusses](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/42319.aspx).

1) You can pre-load all the control IDs that you know you're going to need like this, they query them (he uses jquery) when you need their elements.

```
var ids = { 
    txtSymbol: "#<%= txtSymbol.ClientID %>",
    PageContent: "#<%= PageContainer.ClientID %>"
}
```

This can also be written:

```
var txtSymbol = document.getElementById('<%= txtSymbol.ClientID %>');
var txtBlah = document.getElementById('<%= txtBlah.ClientID %>');
```

2) Or, he wrote a function that will get a control for you from the clientside

```
function $$(id, context) {
    var el = $("#" + id, context);
    if (el.length < 1)
        el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
    return el;
}
```

Be aware that there are some serious caveats.  This relies on JQuery, so be sure to include that library and use it like this $$('myASPControlID').val('new val');  The catch is that if you have any controls that create other controls, like listviews, repeaters, gridviews etc.  Then finding a single instance of a child control will take some strategy.  In that situation, this tool will only get the first instance of a repeated control.

Still, the function provides a way to solve this problem by allowing you to specify a containing element in the second field.

**EDIT**

Hey L G, if you really need to pass your variable from the client side, then just add the second function and a link to the JQuery library.  Then you can get your control with this simple code:

```
var testName = 'txtTest';
var testCntrl = $$(testName);
```

Comment: in javascript we usually do
document.getElementById('<%=txtTest.ClientID %>');
here..the value txtTest i have to pass from a variable..is it possible??

Comment: Hey L G, It is possible, I provided two different methods.  If you know the pool of variable names that you could possibly want before the page loads, use the first method to save their IDs to JavaScript Variable beforehand.  If you won't know them until after the page loads, use the second method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtTest.ClientID %>');
```

Or more along the lines of your original example:

```
var testName = '<%=txtTest.ClientID %>'; 

var testCntrl = document.getElementById(testName);
```

It appears from your example that you have managed to confuse yourself over what is server side and what is client side code.

Answer (score 0):

If it is C# code (which I assume, given the compilation error), you need to surround strings with `"` instead of `'`.

`'` is used for char values, that can contain only one character (or two if it is an escaped one, such as `'\n'`).

But I don't really get the connection between the compilation error and the code, since the C# compiler should not bother about the javascript code...